# How to visualize a set of objects as "fireworks" alike items in pgf/tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a set of objects that are vectors of difrent dimentions. Sometimes objects have same values, all objects are from $R^n$. To display an object as a firework I would like to show each 4 dinentions as a circle on a line distanded from centre something alike this:

[image]

So I wonder how to displat one (or 10 objects from $R^n$ with difrent `n`'s ) in form of "fireworks" in pgf/tikz?

Comment: Please add a minimal example of what you tried so far!

Comment: I messed around this sample http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/electric-dipole/ yet my knowledge is not enough to automate it for more than one tailor maid object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This contains an attempt to answer the question and a commercial.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fireworks/.style args={#1:#2:#3:#4}{insert path={
(0,0)  -- ++ (#1*3.6:#2*1pt) node[circle,draw,fill=blue!#4,inner sep=#3*0.1pt]{}}}]
\draw [fireworks={40:40:60:30},fireworks={10:50:20:90}];
% advertizement
\begin{scope}[xshift=2.5cm]
\duck[body=yellow!80!white,longhair=black,tshirt=magenta!60!white,
jacket=blue,
necklace=white!85!yellow]
\path (0.7,2) rectangle (1.4,2.55);
\fill[yellow!80!orange,rotate=-10,xshift=-11,yshift=5]
    \duckpathcrown;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The duck is, except for some changes of colors, just copied from p.26 of the manual of the stellar `tikzducks` package.

Comment: Oh no, I have the daily vote limit reached, I can't upvote the Duck Queen!

Comment: @CarLaTeX I am reputation capped anyway (and I did not do it for the reputation, but given the user name I simply could not resist ;-).

Comment: Sooo awsome!=))) =*

Comment: @DuckQueen Nice avatar!